# PostgreSQL permission denied for relation error after every database modification

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

I get the following error after every database modification, like new tables, or new column in tables.

`ERROR:  permission denied for relation xxxx`

If I use the GRANT command it solve it, but it's just a temporary solution. Is there a permanent one? I don't want to set the right again with every modification.

Comment: Most probably you are creating the tables with one user, and then trying to use them as another one. So either use the same user, or just use grant to give the other user proper rights.

Comment: You are probably looking for `alter default privileges`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: Thanks, I thought this is the solution, but it's still an issue...